# Matrix multiplication program using pointers shows segmentation fault everytime after taking the order of the matrix

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

My code shows segmentation fault whenever I run it and I dont know where it has went wrong because I think I have done all memory allocations properly please give me some suggestions to debug this problem.

I am using macbook air M1 and it doesnt support gdb yet I guess because I am unable to install it through homebrew and I am unable to find the position where this code is going wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
   int **arr1,**arr2,i,m,n,p,q;
   void matmul(int **,int **,int ,int ,int );
   void read(int **,int , int );
    printf("Enter the order of first matrix\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        arr1[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    read(arr1,m,n);
    printf("Enter the order of second matrix\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&p,&q);
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
        arr2[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*q);
    read(arr2,p,q);
    if(n!=p)
        printf("Matrix multiplication is not possible\n");
    else
        matmul(arr1,arr2,m,q,n);
}

void read(int **arr,int r, int c)
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter the elements\n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            scanf("%d",(arr[i]+j));
}

void disp(int **arr,int r,int c)
{
    int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c;j++)
                printf("%2d",*(arr[i]+j));
            printf("\n");
        }
}

void matmul(int **arr1,int **arr2,int m,int q,int n)
{
    int **arr;
    int k,i,j;
    void disp(int **,int,int);
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*q);
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(j=0;j<1;j++)
            for(k=0;k<n;k++)
                *(arr[i]+j) += (*(arr1[i]+k))*(*(arr2[k]+j));
    disp(arr,m,q);
}
```

Comment: `arr1[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);` You have not allocated memory for `arr1`. Need something like `arr1 = malloc(m * sizeof(*arr1));`. Same for `arr2`.

Comment: A_01_Abhilash S Hathwa, Hint: What is the value of `arr1` right before `for(i=0;i<m;i++)   arr1[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);`?